# destination array was not long enough. check destindex and length and the array's lower bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I have a class with the following code:

```
  Array tags;
  if (lines.Length > 0)
  {
      configText = lines[0];
      tags = new Array[lines.Length];
      lines.CopyTo(tags,1);
  }
```

Here I get the following error:

> Destination array was not long enough. Check destindex and length and
>   the array's lower bounds.

Method:

```
     private bool ReadPointListFile(string fileName) {

        // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element
        // of the array is one line of the file.
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        string configText = string.Empty;

        if (lines.Length > 0)
        {
            configText = lines[0];
            tags = new Array[lines.Length];
            lines.CopyTo(tags,1);
        }
        else
            lines.CopyTo(tags,0);

        GetConfigurationInfo(lines[0], out this.sInterval, out this.dataAggregate);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Show us the whole code. Like, type of 'lines' its contents etc

Answer (score 5):

It will start copy from 1 index not from Zero index, it is creating problem.
Try

```
lines.CopyTo(tags,0);
```

Comment: For the mentioned code: ArrayTypeMismatch Exception Occurs

Comment: what is the type of lines.. is it array or list or else?

Answer (score 1):

tags is array of Array objects which is probably not what you wanted.
If you want to copy from string array (lines), destination array should also be array of strings.
So, where ever you declared tags it should be `string[] tags;`
and in your if block it should be `tags = new string[lines.Length];`

That's the part about types and ArrayTypeMismatch Exception.

Now, if your intention is to copy all but first element, you cant use `CopyTo(tags, 1)` because 1 is for destination array. It indicates where to start writing values. That's why you got your exception.
Instead, just do the loop:
    for(int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        tags[i-1] = lines[i];
    }
Also, in that case, you have one element less for tag array, so you can make it as: `tags = new string[lines.Length-1];`

If you want to skip first index in both lines and tags arrays, then it is `tags = new string[lines.Length];` and `tags[i-1] = lines[i];`